# jQuery date picker won't initialize when hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using this JavaScript plugin: [jQuery Slide Over](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Create-A-Full-Page-Sliding-Panel-Slide-Over.html)

It allows me to display a sliding panel over the main content. I am using this for filtering.

Mostly it works great, but I am having a problem getting jQuery Date Picker to cooperate. It seems that the date picker won't get applied to the input because it starts out hidden. So I tried using the "onOpen" event to apply the date picker.. but this is not working either.

I have created a JS fiddle of the issue here:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cu6kkeud/)

And because SO won't allow me to post a fiddle without the accompanying code, here it is:

**JavaScript**

```
$('#TestDate').datepicker({ maxDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

$('*[data-slideover="open"]').slideOver({
  orientation: 'left',
  animationSpeed: 300,
  overlayColor: 'rgba(18,19,20,0.9)',
  onOpen: function () {
    var selectedDatePicker = $('#SelectedDate');
    if (!selectedDatePicker.hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
      selectedDatePicker.datepicker({ maxDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <a href="#slideover1" class="btn btn-primary" data-slideover="open">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
        </a>

        <div id="slideover1" class="slideover-content">
            FILTERS
            <input type="text" id="SelectedDate" name="SelectedDate" value="2017-01-01" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="main-container" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                BLAH BLAH BLAH
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="TestDate" name="TestDate" value="2017-01-01" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-over{
  width:30%;
  min-width:300px;
}
```

You will see 2 date pickers - 1 of them is in the main content area and works fine (just for demo purposes) and the problematic one is inside the slide out panel, which can be triggered by pressing the button at the top left.

What can I do to get the date picker working inside the slide over panel?

Comment: Not sure if it's the slideover plugin messing up or what exactly is happening, but in the fiddle it looks like pressing the button to open the slideover causes the contents of the "slideover1" div to be copied and appended to the body. The resulting dom has 2 elements with SelectedDate as the id, and the one showing doesn't seem to have the datePicker added to it.

Comment: @Some_Guy, Thanks. You just gave me the idea to try applying a datepicker to a class instead of an ID and it works fine. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it will do for now. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Although there appears to be weird behavior.. like starting in 2017, but clicking "Previous" goes to 1899...  EDIT: Even worse, clicking a date does not change the <input> to that date.. so definitely something still wonky.. but thanks for your having a look anyway

Comment: I agree with Darren Keen that this may not be the best sidebar plugin. Best  thing to do would be to try another

Comment: @Some_Guy, thanks for your help. I decided the simplest thing is Bootstrap modal. It works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin is duplicating the content so essentially you are ending up with 2 selectedText inputs. If you open the filter, right click and inspect the input, change the ID to something else and then run your datepicker code, it works.

If you change to this: var selectedDatePicker = $('.selectedDate'); it will work but not sure how reliable that would be for passing data through a form.

**Update:**
The jumping back to 1899 is an issue due to having 2 inputs with the same ID. Perhaps changing the plugin you use for the slide/looking at their docs & support may help.

**Update:**
Alternate plugin suggestion:
https://simple-sidebar.github.io/simpler-sidebar/

Comment: Thanks. I will play around with it a bit more and try figure out what, if anything can be done... Gonna be a long night... *sigh*

Comment: So I had a look at the JS for the plugin you are using and it has this line:
$(contentId).clone().appendTo('.slide-over');

Its cloning the content and adding it in for sure. Try another plugin - surely be one out there.

**Update**
Something like this https://simple-sidebar.github.io/simpler-sidebar/

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with a simpler solution: Bootstrap Modal.. it's not as cool looking for the filters as a slide out menu would have been, but it's working and it's simple. You get an upvote anyway. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you got something sorted. Happy to help, thanks.